# How to replace the bytes in a binary file?

Tags: python, perl

My binary file `test.bin` contains

```
11 22 33 44 55 66 ...
```

I want to modify the 3rd position with `AA` and my file should be like

```
11 22 33 AA 55 66 ....
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question or shown the code that is giving you trouble. Why have you tagged this with both Python and Perl? Which language are you working in?

Comment: Why have you tagged the question with **Python-Requests**? You don't appear to be using the `Requests` library and your question is nothing to do with HTTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the file for update in binary mode, seek to the desired position in the file, then write the replacement character. The following will work in Python 2 and 3 and will overwrite the 4th byte of the file (3rd position if counting from 0) with 0xAA.

```
with open('test.bin', 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(3)
    f.write(b'\xAA')
```

Comment: if my variable holding hex string and how we will do the above experiment with via variable?

I have tried to do this as follows ,
x='7A'
y=int(x,16)
z='%x' %y
print(z)
with open('test.bin', 'rb+') as f:
 f.seek(3)
 f.write(bz)

And its throwing error like,
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3.py", line 7, in <module>
    f.write(z)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
"

Comment: @NarendraThamatam: you need to write a `bytes` object, not a `str` object. BTW `7A` is a string containing 2 characters. I think that you need to write the single byte with value 0x7A. Convert from a hex string with `binascii.unhexlify(s)`, e.g. `binascii.unhexlify('7A')` will return the bytes object `b'z'`, and `binascii.unhexlify('AA')` will return `b'\xaa'`

Comment: My question is how to pass the hex variable (ex: z=0x7A) to the f.write()?

I am trying it is like, f.write('\x%x'%(z)) but it giving error.

Can you please suggest the best way?

Comment: Thanks mhawke.. Just now I have tried this as follows,

import binascii
x='7A'
z=binascii.unhexlify(x)
with open('test.bin', 'rb+') as f:
 f.seek(3)
 f.write(z)

and its is working fine :)..

Comment: Not working. My test.bin has `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00` and I ran your code it shows following contents of the updated file `\x0ª\x00\x00\x00\x00`